# How to toggle checked radio buttons in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, draggable

I created two radio buttons :

```
<form>
        <p><input type="radio" name="center" value="center">Center</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="right" value="right">Lower Right</p>
    </form>
```

and a jquery script to move the position of a div, it's working, but I have two problems :

1) when I check a radio button , it will not be unchecked when I check the other one, because I am using different names that I will nee for click event.

2)the center positions and the bottom right are hard coded.

Any idea will be appreciated.

```
<script>
            $(function(){
                $(init);
                function init(){
                    $('#target').draggable();
                }
                $('input[name=center]:radio').click(function(){
                    $('#target').css({
                        position:'absolute',
                        top:200 + 'px',
                        left:45 + 'px'
                    });
                });
                $('input[name=right]:radio').click(function(){
                    $('#target').css({
                        position:'absolute',
                        top:550 + 'px',
                        right:200 + 'px'
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: Why not use an `ID` attribute to differentiate the elements in your click event handler, and keep the radiobutton names the same?  That way, you don't have to hack a solution; you can just use the default functionality of the browser.

Comment: @Dan - That sure seems like the right answer to me. You should post it, and we will upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ID attribute to differentiate the elements in your click event handler.  Keep the radiobutton names the same.  That way, you don't have to hack a solution; you can just use the default functionality of the browser:

```
<form>
    <p><input type="radio" id="center" name="someFormValue" value="center" />Center</p>
    <p><input type="radio" id="right" name="someFormValue" value="right" />Lower Right</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Dan. the positions (center and lower right( are still not dynamically calculated.